Dropzone Cropping Final Cut Pro
I'm using PremiumVFX Simple Split Screens, when I use some compound clips within a drop zone they are strangely cropped. I can't work out why and other clips seem to work.
I don't think it's the fault of PremiumVFX, there's something different in the clips.

As I'm not a power user I'm not even sure I'm using the right terminology. Does anyone have any ideas?

The difference between the clips seems to be an adjustment layer. I still don't know how to solve it.
